# Magento product, migration

Tags: php, magento, migration, magento-1.8

I am working on migration activity may old store to Magento enterprise. I would like to know best way for Order migration migration. Below are my approach for migration.

1. Product : I am using magmi mass importer which very fast then Magento default import.
2. Customer : I have 50,000 Customer to import. I have a create Custom php script for it. Is there any other way to make it fast?
3. Order : I have 1L orders to import Which is taking to much time by custom script for order create. Is there any other way for migrate order fast ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem's that most of the stores have a custom database structure, so that's really problem to find general tools to migrate between custom store -> Magento.

IMHO, based on my experience, best way to migrate is to create shell scripts - won't take a time for parsing html by browser and using simplest php function to fetch data from old store database.

Magento have also a complex database structure (EAV) so if you want to avoid any lacks of the data, you need use Magento models.

Best.